# Function composition left to right

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell. Some expression:

```
replicate 2 . product . map (*3) $ zipWith max [1,2] [4,5]
```

When I build it I write the `zipWith max [1,2] [4,5]` at first, then I press the `Home` key and write the `map (*3) $`, then I press the `Home` key again and write the `product .`, then I press the `Home` key and write the `replicate 2 .`. This way is inconvenient to me.

So I build an expression right to left,and when I am reading this - I do it right to left too. But I got used to read left to right - this is more convenient to me.

I can do the same left to right:

```
zipWith max [1,2] [4,5] # map (*3) # product # replicate 2
```

This case I am writting\reading an expression left to right, as I got used, without the `Home` key pressing.

I define the `#` function as:

```
infixl 0 #
(#) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
n # f = (f) n
```

So, the `#` function creates the *function composition*, like the `.` function, but it works left to right.

For example, this functions are equal:

```
someFunc :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Int
someFunc f n = length . takeWhile (< n) $ scanl1 (+) (map (f) [1..])

someFunc' :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Int
someFunc' f n = map (f) [1..] # scanl1 (+) # takeWhile (< n) # length
```

But the `someFunc'` is more convenient for me for reading\writting.

I am thinking to use the `#` function in my code instead the `.`. Are exist some problems with the `#` function which I not see still?

Comment: `lens` defines this operator as `&` with `infixl 1 &` instead, and I believe F# uses the `|>` operator or something like it for a similar effect, but I haven't really used F# so I may be lying.

Comment: @bheklilr you are correct.

Comment: Your `(#)` operator is flipped function *application*, not function composition. You may want to consider the difference between `f $ g $ h $ a` and `f . g . h $ a`. Some authors and languages do prefer flipped composition, btw, so this is a pretty reasonable thing to want. You can define `(>>>) = flip (.)` and use it as `numEvens = filter even >>> length`.

Comment: @Rein Henrichs, you are right. I am mistaking: my `#` function is a flipped function application. Ok, but what it influences? I want to use it for left to right writting\reading of my code. Name of `#` has the single char and the `>>>` has three chars, i.e. first variant shortly. The question which I asked in a subject, still is actual for me.

Comment: @bheklilr `|>` in F# isn't function composition, but application. But you are right about the order.

Comment: Your `#` function is _not_ function composition. You should define it as `(#) = flip (.)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `#` is, as bheklir notes, `&` from `lens`, which is reverse *application*. Reverse *composition*, however, is `>>>` from `Control.Category`.

Comment: >Reverse composition, however, is >>> from Control.Category.< But ghci is not see the `>>>` function in the `Control.Category` module: 
`λ: :m + Control.Category
λ: :t >>>

<interactive>:1:1: parse error on input `>>>'
λ: :t Control.Category.>>>

<interactive>:1:1: parse error on input `Control.Category.>>>'
λ:`

Comment: You need to surround operators with `()`s to use them in non-infix ways: `:t (>>>)` would work fine.

Comment: Thank you. I try to use the `>>>` instead of `#`: 
`import Control.Category
someFunc2 :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Int
someFunc2 f n = map (f) [1..] >>> scanl1 (+) >>> takeWhile (< n) >>> length` but ghci can't load this. I see that a signature of `>>>` is not the same as `#`

Comment: @Bush `Prelude Control.Arrow> ($ zipWith max [1,2] [4,5]) $ map (*3) >>> product >>> replicate 2` **=>** `[180,180]`.

Comment: `($)` is to `(.)` as `(&)` is to `(>>>)`

Comment: @Bush or, `Prelude> let x |> f = f x` ; 
`Prelude> zipWith max [1,2] [4,5] |> map (*3) |> product |> replicate 2` **=>** `[180,180]`.

Comment: @Bush Hi =)  And for the record it literally doesn't mean anything.  I made it up about a decade ago.

Comment: @Will Ness, I try to do: `λ: :m + Control.Arrow
λ: ($ zipWith max [1,2] [4,5]) $ map (*3) >>> product >>> replicate 2 => [180,180]` but I get an error: <interactive>:2:68: parse error on input `=>'

Comment: @Will Ness, I get the same error for your second variant too.

Comment: @dfeuer, but my `#` works like a reverse *composition* and this is not necessary the reverse *application*. Look my `someFunc'` function please. Its first expression (the `map` calling) has two arguments.